# Tightly Coupling pallet error: ambiguous associated type `Currency` in bounds of `T`

Tags: substrate, polkadot

I have following config file, I added schelling game pallet as tightly coupling pallet:

```
 use frame_support::{
    traits::{Currency, ExistenceRequirement, Get, ReservableCurrency, WithdrawReasons},
};    
#[pallet::config]
pub trait Config: frame_system::Config + schelling_game::Config{
    type Event: From<Event<Self>> + IsType<<Self as frame_system::Config>::Event>;

    type Currency: ReservableCurrency<Self::AccountId>;

    type RandomnessSource: Randomness<Self::Hash, Self::BlockNumber>;
}
```

I have following code in the function:

```
#[pallet::weight(10_000 + T::DbWeight::get().reads_writes(2,2))]
    pub fn add_profile_fund(origin: OriginFor<T>, citizenid: u128) -> DispatchResult {
        let who = ensure_signed(origin)?;       
        let deposit = <RegistrationFee<T>>::get();

        let imb = T::Currency::withdraw(
            &who,
            deposit,
            WithdrawReasons::TRANSFER,
            ExistenceRequirement::AllowDeath,
        )?;
```

It gives error:

ambiguous associated type `Currency` in bounds of `T`

ambiguous associated type `Currency`

note: associated type `T` could derive from `schelling_game::Config`
help: use fully qualified syntax to disambiguate: `<T as pallet::Config>::Currency`

When I add

```
let imb = <T as frame_system::Config>::Currency::withdraw()
```

It gives error:
cannot find associated type `Currency` in trait `frame_system::Config`

not found in `frame_system::Config`

Edit:
The error is because I have used currency trait in both the pallet. How can I use currency trait in both pallets?

Comment: Hey, would you be so kind as to repost this great question on https://substrate.stackexchange.com/ -- and @NukeManDan over there?
Very happy to assist on our shiny new Substrate (and friends) home for your questions! We can cross post the answer here we arrive at there. -- seeing as we have an answer we can just migrate (cleaned up with the commentary to clarify :) )

Answer (score 0):

I think the error/warning message has given you the answer you need  . Could you try:

```rust
let imb = <T as pallet::Config>::Currency::withdraw();
```

and see if this works?

What I am not sure how is `Currency` ambiguous, as the associated type is only defined in your pallet and not in [**System Pallet**](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/latest/frame_system/pallet/trait.Config.html)? But well, if the compiler tells us to do so, let's not argue with it for now.

---

Update:

oh, I think the `pallet` module exports the `Config` trait out and the trait is now accessible as `schelling_game::Config` also as mentioned in the error message. So there are two names now - `pallet::Config` and `schelling_game::Config` and rust compiler treats them as ambiguous, but they are the same thing really.

Comment: It gives error:  failed to resolve: use of undeclared crate or module `pallet`

use of undeclared crate or module `pallet`

Comment: Sorry I am using currency trait in both of my pallets, that why the error. How can I use currency trait in both pallets.